# Proper Request and response pattern using Inheritance, generics, interfaces c#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I've got an interface for requests and an interface for responses. I want to call something like this

```
        public IResponse Get(IRequest req)
```

The request object is serialized and sent out on a bus.

I get a response back but I need to deserialize the response into the IResponse class that corresponds with the specific IRequest class. What's the right way to tie a response to a request so that whenever someone implements one of these request/response pairs they have to constrain it to a certain type?

Here's what I've tried:

```
public interface IRequest<T> where T : IResponse
{
    Type GetResponseType(T t);
}
public interface IResponse { }

public class Res : IResponse
{
    public string response { get; set; }
}

public class Req : IRequest<Res>
{
    public string request { get; set; }

    public Type GetResponseType(Res t)
    {
        return t.GetType();
    }
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to pass in an IRequest now:

```
public IResponse Get(IRequest req)
```

I get the error:

> Using the generic type 'IRequest' requires 1 types argument

I tried:

```
public IResponse Get(IRequest<IResponse> req)
```

But when I try to pass in my class I get:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Req' to 'IRequest<(IResponse)>'

Does anyone know the proper way to do something like this, or at least let me know how to get my class to work as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could construct your method like that:

```
public IResponse Get<T>(IRequest<T> req) where T : IResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the signature, I'd use what Pawel suggests:

```
public IResponse Get<T>(IRequest<T> req) where T : IResponse
```

Regarding the implementation - do you really need a parameter for the GetResponseType) method? I ask because it seems like GetResponseType is tied to the generic type T and can always be inferred from it. The code below illustrates the point I am trying to make.

```
public interface IRequest<T> where T : IResponse
{
    Type GetResponseType();
}
public interface IResponse { }

public class Res : IResponse
{
    public string response { get; set; }
}

public class Req : IRequest<Res>
{
    public string request { get; set; }

    public Type GetResponseType()
    {
        return typeof(Res);
    }
}
```